# Selectize load function is not showing options in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-select2, selectize.js

**Usecase**
There are a total of 200000 records exist in my database, if i load all the option in one time the  page is not loading at all, it is saying maximum transaction time crossed (i felt like its the worst approach).

I thought of loading the **selectize options** based on **keyword search**, i will show the **50** records close to the search keyword.

I implemented the search in backend(Serverside), it is returning the data correctly to the client but i'm not finding a way to show them as options in html.

```
Please find my code below:
```

```js
$scope.$selectUser = $('#selectUser').selectize({
    valueField: 'sys_id',
    labelField: 'name',
    maxItems: c.data.maxteam,
    placeholder:"Enter names or select below",
    create: false,
    load: function (query, callback) {
    
        if (!query.length) return callback();
         
        $scope.data.funcName = 'getUsers';
        $scope.data.searchQuery = query;
        $scope.data.kudosTo = [];
        
        //Server call happens here
        c.server.update().then(function(){ 
             
            //Search data coming fine in this variable
            var results = c.data.activeUsers; 
            
            //??? AT this step i'm not what to do to appear the data as selectize options and select from them ??
            
            callback(results);
             
             
        });
    },
    render: {
        option: function (item, escape) {
            return '<div class="option">' +
            '<div class="text">' +
            '<span class="name">' + escape(item.name) +"<i class='fa fa-circle circleFont'></i>"+ escape(item.user_name)  + '</span>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';
        }
    },
});
$scope.selectizeControlUser = $scope.$selectUser[0].selectize;
```

```html
<div class="form-group text-left  clearfix">
    <select class="form-control" id="selectUser"  multiple></select>
</div>
```

**Search data coming fine in client code:**
[image]

**Issue: Selectize options are **not** showing in the HTML view**
[image]

Expected results: Options should come like below image
[image]

Comment: it gives the impression that your jQuery plugin is not up to par. And now that the javascript is very well developed (ES2021), it will surprise me that this plugin follows the updates, like many other jQuery pluggins which have also ended up being abandoned.

Comment: @MisterJojo  No issues with my plugin, I'm 100% sure!! i'm not just clear about, how to show the data as options using `load` function for selectize.
Unfortunately our dev environment (Servicenow) only supports ES5,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out myself.

Options are appending to the options but just not showing in the view.

I added **searchField** and it started working fine as expected.

```
searchField: ['name', 'email', 'user_name'],
```